# Javascript - Using return in function doesn't terminate function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video

I'm in the process of creating my own HTML5 video player and packaging it as a reusable jQuery plugin. I need to terminate a function part way through, because when i press play, the player would play, then pause itself, if there is an odd number of times that a player is created afterwards.

HTML controlset markup (This is inserted using javascript)

```
<div class="meo">
    <video>
        <source src="example.mp4">
        <source src="example.webm">
    </video>
    <ul>
        <li class="playp"></li> <!-- Ignore everything between here -->
        <li class="ctime"></li>
        <li class="progr">
            <div class="progb"></div>
        </li>
        <li class="ttime"></li>
        <li class="fs"></li> <!-- and here -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$.fn.meo = function() {
    return this.each(function() {
        var vid = $(this);
        var playp = $(".meo .playp");
        vid.wrap('<div class="meo"></div>');
        vid.after('<ul><li class="playp"></li><li class="ctime"></li><li class="progr"><div class="progb"></div></li><li class="ttime"></li><li class="fs"></li></ul>');

        $.fn.handlePlay = function() {
            var video = $(this).parent().siblings().get(0); // Getting the correct video element
            alert(video); // To show value of "video" (Returns multiple times depending on how many of the controlsets as above are found (This is not what I want))
            if (video.paused || video.ended) { // Testing if the video is playing
                video.play(); // After this I want to prevent the rest of the function executing
                return;
            } else {
                video.pause();
                return; // Terminate function
            };
        };

        playp.click(function(e) {
            $(this).handlePlay();
        });
    });
});
```

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: I think you should use `return false;`

Comment: would you like to terminate the function or to stop the iteration?

Comment: terminate the function

Comment: `playp.click(function(e) {` this is going to setup multiple click handlers for elements `.meo .playp` that were created before. You should use a delegated event. Also your function `handlePlay` is going to terminate right after the if blocks anyway so unless you have code you are not showing there is no difference in the return statements being there or not

Comment: @mortezaT It didn't work

Comment: @PatrickEvans so I don't need the second 'return' or do I not need either

Comment: If there is no code after the if statement within `handlePlay` then you don't need either

Comment: @PatrickEvans thanks, but I not really sure about how to use the delegated event. I'm sorry for sounding really unexperienced and troubling you

Comment: The 2x `return;` you currently have return from the `$.fn.handlePlay()` block.  (as pointed out in comments, they are the last statement in that block, so have no real effect).

Comment: The code at comment `//Terminate function` is currently "inside" **three** "functions" (and called from another).  It's not clear at which level you are expecting to "terminate".

Comment: @freedomn-m Sorry, I want to terminate the handlePlay() function

Comment: Ok - in which case, to confirm, it already does as there are no statements after it.  It's most likely getting *called* multiple times. Try adding a console.log (or alert) inside the function to see how many times it's being called `$.fn.handlePlay = function() { alert("handle play"); ... ` It looks to me that it should be defined *outside* the `$.fn.meo` definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
playp.click(function(e) {
   $(this).handlePlay();
});
```

This is going to setup a click event handler every time `$.each()` iterates. This means `handlePlay()` is going to be called multiple times even though you click an element only once.

Either use a delegated event handler or use the newly created element only to attach the event handler

Delegated event: use a static parent element to apply the event handler to

```
$(document).on("click",".meo .playp",function(){
  $(this).handlePlay();
});
$.fn.meo = function() {...};
```

Or set the event on the newly created element itself

```
vid.find(".playp").click(function(){
    $(this).handlePlay();
});
```

Also you do not need to create `$.fn.handlePlay` each time in `this.each()` either, so that can be moved outside it.

```
 $.fn.handlePlay = function() { ... }
 $.fn.meo = function() { ... }
```